# how to access config variable from javascript spring-boot

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I'm looking how to access a config variable that located in 'config/XXX-web.xml' file from javascript.

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="name">superman</string>
</resources>
```

How would I access the name from javascript or the JSP file?